# How to stop update on keyup if the error message is the same with Jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Whenever I type in Jquery validated field on max and min number of letters, I get a refresh of messages even though the error is the same. How do I prevent that so it is less irritating for the users?

The code is

```js
    validations = {
        'rules':{
            'code': {
                'minlength': 9,
                'maxlength': 9
            },

        },
        'messages': {
            'code': {
                'minlength': 'Must be 9 digits',
                'maxlength': 'Must be 9 digits'
            },
        }
    }
```

I have tried to use `showerror()`, and check whether the error list is the same, but I can't prevent the previous error messages from disappearing.

```js
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if(typeof prev_error_map != "undefined"){
                if (!_.isEqual(prev_error_map, errorMap)) {
                    this.defaultShowErrors();
                    prev_error_map = errorMap;
                }
            }else{
                this.defaultShowErrors();
                prev_error_map = errorMap;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How can we help you without seeing your code?  What are your validation rules on the field that is being annoying?  Typically, the messages do not flash so it would be interesting to see how you've set this up.  `showErrors()` does not have anything to do with how the messages are triggered.  Did you read the plugin's official documentation?   It tells you how to disable the `onkeyup` validation trigger.

Comment: I don't want to disable onkeyup trigger. I want to update the error message only when it is different. For now it updates on every keyup event.

Comment: Did you try the `onkeyup: false` option yet?  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup

Comment: I tried it. When ```onkeyup: false``` is used, the error is removed whenever input is entered, the validation doesn't kick in until ```onblur```.  However, I want to have the error persist until user has the right input.

Comment: *"I don't want to disable onkeyup trigger. I want to update the error message only when it is different.  For now it updates on every keyup event."* - And it's literally different after each and every keyup.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my mistake. Instead of doing

```
'minlength': x,
'maxlength': y
```

I should have done

```
'rangelength': [x,y]
```

This way, the length is only checked once and potential updates are avoided.